# Showing data values on horizontal stacked bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I would like to add the values of on this horizontal stacked bar chart but can't manage to put it properly. Late I would like to add additional text on the different bars but don't know how to start.

```
il <- ggplot(p11, aes(x = question, y = q.int.local))+
  geom_col(aes(fill = knowledge), width = 0.7)+ 
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CA463F", "#E2CA58", "#B0D094", "#67BBD2", "#3C518F"))+
  geom_text(aes(label = q.int.local),color="white",size=2,position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust=-0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: As you want to place labels on a stacked barchart try with `geom_text(..., position = position_stack(vjust = .5))`  instead of using `position_dodge`.

Comment: When I try this is what I get... 

Error in `check_subclass()`:
! `x` must be either a string or a <Position> object, not a function.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.